# AWS - Link EC2 Folders to file transfer solution

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp, ftps

I have the following scenario - I have EC2 server that has different customer named folders (for example customer1 and customer2), I need to provide a service that will allow customers to eventually upload their files to the destination customer specific folder (customer 1 uploads file through some service and the only possible destination would be customer1 folder on the EC2). There is a service that scans these folders locally and that is why this setup is needed. The issue is I have setup this with FTPS and now the solution requires SFTP or something better like S3 endpoint integration, but I can't decide which is the way to achieve this with SFTP or with S3 or with something else like Lambda.

Comment: If you can expand on your scenario more, and try to make it a bit easier to read, you might get some useful replies. For example, how technical are the users? Are they people or automated systems? Is any particular protocol required? What storage and bandwidth do you need? What size files are you transferring? etc.

Comment: My main concern is the service to be able to auto fill in the files in the EC2 directories, I am not sure how to do that with AWS SFTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For HA sftp best option for production grade solution will be aws sftp https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/ or some production grade sftp server.

Comment: Agree the AWS SFTP solution is good if you need very high reliability, but it costs the same as three m5.large instances running 24x7 - about $200 per month plus storage costs. I googled "FTP as a service" and found [this service](https://ftphosting.net/pricing.php) for $25 per month with 25GB of storage - this is just an example, not a recommendation.

Comment: Agree with you @Tim, if we really looking for cheap solution, we need to build our own and for it will come with resource and maintenance cost too. So we have to choose based on our restrictions.

Comment: I have a service that is expecting files to be handed to a specific EC2 directory based on user credentials. Right now I am using File Zilla server but it only supports FTPS I have a requirement to switch to SFTP or something that is on the same level of security or better and open less or no ports on customer side. The load will be occasional, file import of 10-100 MB files, I don't expect more than 20 users with more than 10 imports per each monthly. I need to make sure that the transfer would be always available.

Comment: With AWS SFTP service you could have your instance run an "aws s3 sync" cli command on cron to pull the files into EC2, then optionally delete them from S3. If all you need is a different protocol then what you should probably do is just search for FTP server software that supports the protocol you want. SFTP is ssh file transfer protocol, it's built into SSH. You could probably create local users on the instance and use ssh to enable SFTP, but it's probably more work that way.

Comment: @Tim, this was really helpful, I think I will try the SFTP service because we may have broader use case for it, even if the cost is a bit high. I think I will try the aws s3 sync, but will I look for some event based triggering if possible.